# CSS .hover проблемы с трансикцией - проблиски и задержка

Tags: css, hover

При использовании следующего класса:

```css
a.butt {
  display: block;
  width: 650px;
  height: 330px;
  background: url(http://b1.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

a.butt:hover {
  background-image: url(b2.png);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://blabla" target="_blank" class="butt">zina</a>
```

пробликивает белый цвет. Чувство, что транзикция медленная и не кешируется быстро, но не уверен.

Как подправить, чтобы не было задержки и белых бликов?

Пробовал на `ie11`, `opera`, `chrome`.

Comment: Как-будто школьник писал

Comment: какая вообще транзикция когда ты меняешь бэкграунд?

Comment: @Herrgott, похоже на то, что он имеет ввиду, что смена `:hover` проскакивает сначала, а после появляется - к сожалению вы не в силах это изменить, это заложено в браузере.

Comment: и смена бг по ховеру это треш

Comment: @And , именно это и имел ввиду, я просто нешарющий, я метод нашол - пользую, посоветуйте что лучше.

Comment: @qipio, Вы это не исправите, пользуйтесь, тем, что есть.

Comment: @And со всем уважением но с такой логикой далеко не пойдешь, спасибо конечно за ответ, но я буду искать другие вырианти....

Comment: @qipio, какой логикой, и что вы там будете искать? Новый псевдо элемент `:hover` ? У вас картинка, которая при наведение появляется и пока не загружена, она как-раз изчезает и появляется после загрузки, а только после падает в кеш. И увы, уж от нас это никак не влияет.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что при: замене картинки, ее адреса, других модификаций (она будет сначала загружаться (скачиваться)), а только после кешируется в браузерном хранилище.

По этому с картинками - не получиться работать нативно (как например с простым цветом)

```
a{background:#ffffff;}
a:hover{background:#000000;}
```

Так и с другими нативными модификациями.
Работает мего-быстро - это заложено в браузере.

В Вашем случае, Вы, указываете пусть к картинке, которую нужно скачать и сохранить в хранилище (кешировать), по этому `:hover` тут не причем.

Логика простая: `Есть картинка? Показываем! Нет картинки? Скачиваем! Показываем!`
Отсюда и задержки и блики и пустота.

По этому иногда когда заходишь на некоторые сайты, они начинают скакать и появляются картинки, все это происходит из-за:
1. Не фиксированных размеров блоков страницы
2. Загрузки изображений

Вы можете для себя сделать макет из разноцветных квадратов и посмотреть на сколько быстро загружается и меняется `:hover` и сделать на картинках и Вы, сразу увидите разницу.

Comment: Спасибо за подробности, и все понятно ну вот только : какой "псевдо ховер" найти чтобы изменить систему но иметь тот же результат, анимацией может, прекеширование? Я просто только начинаю копаться, и всё-же новичок.

Comment: @qipio, другого такого в css нет, как вариант, отдавать сразу 2 картинки, а по `:hover`, ставить первой картинке `display:none;` или `visibility:hidden;`, а вторую показывать по `display:inline-block;` или `visibility:visible;`.